# MongoDB Single or Compound index for sorted query?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing

I'm using mongoose and I have a query like this:

```
const stories = await Story.find({ genre: 'romance' }).sort({ createdAt: -1 })
```

I want to set an index on Story so that this kind of query becomes faster.

Which one of these is the best approach and why:

**1. Create one Compound index with both fields:**

```
Story.createIndex({genre: 1, createdAt: -1})
```

**2. Create two separate indexes on each field:**

```
Story.createIndex({genre: 1})
Story.createIndex({createdAt: -1})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "genre" is always going to be part of the search field, using a compound index will always result in better performance.

1.) A Compound index consisting of the field being searched and the field that it is being sorted on can satisfy both the conditions.

2.) Creating more than one indexes assumes that, both the indexes will be used while fulfilling the query, that is not true. Index intersection concept is only applicable in a few circumstances. In this particular instance, since we have one field in the search criteria and another in sort, index intersection will not be employed by Mongo. ([Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort)).

So in this situation, I would go with the compound index.

Comment: Thanks, That is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all your queries that need to use the `createdAt` field, use the `genre`  field as well you should use the **compound index.**

Lets compare the two options:

**Queries:** As long as what i stated above holds both queries will behave **the same**, There is no difference between those two when it comes to query execution speed.

**Memory:** A compound index will use less memory, which is crucial if you have limited RAM space. lets see the difference with an example:

Lets have 3 documents:

```
{
 name: "john",
 last_name: "mayer"
}
{
 name: "john",
 last_name: "cake"
}
{
 name: "banana",
 last_name: "pie"
}
```

Now if we run `db.collection.stats()` on option 1 the compound index we get:

`totalIndexSize: 53248.0`

On the contrary for option 2:

`totalIndexSize: 69632.0`

**Inserting:** full disclosure I have no idea how each is affected. from small tests it seems that a compound index is slightly quicker, however I could not really find documentation on this nor did I investigate deeper.

Comment: Thanks for the comparison, but I still can't decide which kind of indexing to use, currently I don't have memory issues and speed is what matters the most in my case, so if in my scenario, using compound index is faster, and the memory overhead is negligible I'm willing to use the compound index.

Comment: maybe i wasent clear, the compound is more memory efficient, and i wouldn't say the overhead is negligible without knowing your scale. however in terms of sheer query speed (which what matters to you) they both act **the same**, the two separate index's just gives you more flexibility.

Comment: Oh Thanks! I thought single indexes make this query use each index separately, so it would become slower